# VirtualBox 7.0 Win10Pro <-> Win10Pro . Clipboard stopped working

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, clipboard

I have installed **VirtualBox 7.0 with extensions** on a **Win10 pro machine** and run a VM with also **Win 10 pro** in the VM.
The bidirectional clipboard **has worked** and **now does not work anymore**.
[image]

The (actual) newest **version 7.0** is installed **( 1 )**
The settings to the clipboard **are done ( 2 )**
[image]
On the guest OS, the **clipboard options ( 3 )** also are showed end **set correct ( 4 )**
In the windows features:
Hyper-V, Microsoft Defender Application Guard and VM-Platform are **not** set.
As I wrote, the clipboard **has** worked, but now stopped to work (without any change from my side, but - maybe - there were some changes thru a windows update..).
**Thanks a lot for any hint, what this can be (always read the questions here to this theme).**

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself (in a youtube video).
I had to install the **VBoxWindowsAdditions ( 2 )** in addition **on the VM**.
On the VM automatically, a virtual CD drive **( 1 )** is added, where the additions are stored (I assume, this was done by the installation of the extensions to VB).
Very strange for me, as it has worked right after the VB installation without this additional install.
**However, it works now..**
[image]